# Javascript function from specific media query

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I have problem with navigation on my website. When I am on mobile version, I have typical burger navigation and I have this .js to cover that menu in the side when clicking on any item in the menu :

```
const navClose = () => {
    const navbut = document.querySelector('.navbut');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-bar');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-bar li');

    document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links a").forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click",() => {
        navbut.classList.remove("toggle");
        nav.classList.remove("nav-active");

        navLinks.forEach((link,index)=>{
            if(link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = ''
            } else{
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
            }
        });

    }))
}

navClose()
```

But when I have desktop version and I click on the items it flashs and adds that style animation :

```
link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
```

to every item in the menu, it does the animation and looks horrible.
Is there any code that makes the function functional only when for example @media screen and (max-width:860px) ?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.matchMedia`:

```js
const isMobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 860px)');
```

[Window.matchMedia() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)